# How to display one rows from the two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have `type` column in my table, `type` column value is `HOT` and`NOT`.  from that i want to display `HOT` and `NOT` values of the column in to one line.

Example

Table1

```
Period ID Total

11/2011 101 250
12/2011 102 350
11/2011 103 450
....
```

Table2

```
Period ID Type Value

11/2011 101 NOT 500
11/2011 101 HOT 200
12/2011 102 NOT 300
12/2011 102 HOT 200
....
```

I want to display type (`Hot` and `Not`) in to one line

Expected Output

```
Period ID NOT HOT Total

11/2011 101 500 200 250
12/2011 102 300 200 350
11/2011 103 300 400 450
....
```

How to make a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I can assume that table1 has a primary key of (Period, ID) and table2 has a primary key of (Period, ID, Type), then you can do:

```
select
    t1.period
    , t1.id
    , t2n.value [not]
    , t2h.value [hot]
    , t1.total
from
    table1 t1
    left join table2 t2n
        on t1.period = t2n.period
        and t1.id = t2n.id
        and t2n.type = 'Not'
    left join table2 t2h
        on t1.period = t2h.period
        and t1.id = t2h.id
        and t2h.type = 'Hot'
```

This will retrieve all rows from table 1, with their corresponding "not" and "hot" counterparts, respective to t2n and t2h above.

Comment: +1. It is also likely that `(ID)` is `Table1`'s PK and `(ID, Type)` `Table2`'s, and `Table2.Period` is a redundant column that just duplicates `Table1.Period`.

Comment: @CD Jorgensen, It's working, but in table2 i have more period then table1, so i want to display all ther period from table2 and table 2 same period of table1

Comment: @RemoRose: Try full joins instead of left joins; in order to pull correct results for `period` and `id`, play with `CASE` expressions or `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
select base.period, base.id, sum( notchild.value ) as notsum, sum( hotchild.value ) as hotsum, base.total
from table1 base
left outer join table2 notchild 
    on base.period = notchild.period and base.id = notchild.id and notchild.type = 'NOT'
left outer join table2 hotchild 
    on base.period = hotchild.period and base.id = hotchild.id and hotchild.type = 'HOT'
group by base.period, base.id, base.total
```

Comment: You probably forgot to add `notchild.type = 'NOT'` and `hotchild.type = 'HOT'` somewhere (most likely, to the join conditions).

Comment: You're absolutely right!  Sorry to the original poster.  I'll amend the answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN`(Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)) to do this. Join your two tables and perform a `SELECT` on it.